# Stream Video from a Satellite Using C# and .NET 4 and Silverlight Technology

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

Hi can someone point me in the write direction. I would like to be able to stream video to the internet from the Glory TV satellite and have no idea on where to start.

I'm learning C#, ASP.NET and Silverlight but need to know how to stream videos from a satellite. I'd like the site to be something like HULU but don't have a clue where to start but i know the technologies i want to use to do.

I've already looked at some of the free open sources silverlight video players i can use.

Are there some similar sites or services api's available that i can look at to get started or learn how to implement this or even books. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Lanesa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these out :

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/101837/237098.aspx

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/21970/77051.aspx

http://www.learn-silverlight-tutorial.com/StreamingMediaUsingSilverlight.cfm

Comment: This was very helpful as well...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_sayed/archive/2010/01/07/hosting-videos-on-windows-azure.aspx